# How can I validate an array of strings from a JSON in Golang with validator package?

Tags: go, validation, go-playground

I'm using the package validator to help me deal with JSON fields in golang. I know how to use oneof to check for specific values in a field.
Is there any option for doing the same, but for an array of strings?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
type ResponseEntity struct {
    Values       []string  `json:"values" validate:"oneof=VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3"`
}
```

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Dive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mkopriva points out, you can use the [`dive`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Dive) keyword to check the elements of a slice.

To offer more explanation:

- some rules, like [`min`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Minimum) are overloaded and apply to both scalar and slice types
- other rules, like [`oneof`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-One_Of) apply only to scalars; (in [the example below](https://go.dev/play/p/XujNMhaq-er), a call to `validate.Struct` causes a panic when the struct has a `oneof` rule directly on a slice)
- `dive` pushes rules like `oneof` down to the elements of a slice. (the example also shows `min`, `dive`, and `oneof` working together without panicking).

```go
type (
    demoA struct {
        Values []string `validate:"oneof=VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3"`
    }
    demoB struct {
        Values []string `validate:"min=1"`
    }
    demoC struct {
        Values []string `validate:"min=1,dive,oneof=VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3"`
    }
)

var validate = validator.New()

func main() {
    safeValidate(demoA{[]string{}})
    fmt.Println()

    doValidate(demoB{[]string{}})
    doValidate(demoB{[]string{"foo"}})
    fmt.Println()

    doValidate(demoC{[]string{}})
    doValidate(demoC{[]string{"foo"}})
    doValidate(demoC{[]string{"VALUE2"}})
    fmt.Println()
}
```